# Am I correctly implementing the Factory Design Pattern? How can I improve this architecture?

Tags: c#, json, architecture, factory-pattern

I'm trying to use correct design patterns and naming schemes to improve my formal coding abilities.  I have a situation I could use some help with.

I'm trying to make a Global Factory Service that constructs various Models based on data that is organized in various Database files.  I'd love some feedback on the current structure and what I can do differently to improve it.

Currently I think I'm doing too many things in my `CataloguesFactory` class and I would like to know where and how to split it into components.  Additionally, I'm not sure if the naming scheme is correct... or even if the basic architecture is correct!

Current File Structure:

```
Catalogues
    ├── Database
    │    ├── Object1Definition.json
    │    └── ...
    ├── Object1Catalogue.cs
    └── ...
Models
    ├── Object1Model.cs
    └── ...
Services
    └── CataloguesFactory.cs
```

Within the `Catalogues` folder I have various `.json` files that hold the definitions for objects - the plan is to eventually have these on a database online with the ability to update the Database's content dynamically without .  These definitions are then translated to a Catalogue, which is stored in and referenced by the `CataloguesFactory` in order to construct the `Models`.

The files themselves look like this:

Object1Definition.json: Contains basic definitions for all objects.

```
{
    object1List:
    [
        {
            "slug": "first-object",
            "property1": "Lorem",
            "property2": 4
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Object1Catalogue.cs: This is a conversion of the objects from `json` format to `cs` format.  Within the `Item` is contained a `ToModel()` function which accepts some form of modifier parameter which will assist the `Item` in building the final `Model`.

```
public class Object1Catalogue
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string slug;
        public string property1;
        public int property2;

        public Object1Model ToModel(int modifier)
        {
            var obj = new Object1Model();
            obj.Slug = slug;
            obj.Property1 = property1;
            obj.Property2 = property2 * modifier;
        }
    }

    public Object1Catalogue.Item[] object1List;
}
```

Object1Model.cs: This is the object that the Factory produces, based on the Database and some modifiers fed in on a Get request.  Additional functionality may be provided to these Models (maybe Model isn't the correct Suffix here either).

```
public class Object1Model
{
    public string Slug;
    public string Property1;
    public int Property2;

    override public string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Slug}: {Property1} {Property2.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

CataloguesFactory.cs: This is a Service that's also a Singleton.  Right now it has 3 responsibilities: (1) Convert the `json` files to objects in a list, (2) Store the resulting objects and (3) expose the `Get` functions which allow external classes to construct factory objects.

```
public class CataloguesFactory
{
    private CataloguesFactory() { Initialize(); }
    private static readonly Lazy<CataloguesFactory> lazy = new Lazy<CataloguesFactory>(() => new CataloguesFactory());
    public static CataloguesFactory Instance { get => lazy.Value; }

    private string DATABASE_PATH = $"{Application.dataPath}/Catalogues/Database";

    private Object1Catalogue Object1Catalogue;
    ...

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Object1Catalogue = StreamData<Object1Catalogue>("Object1Definition.json");
        ...
    }

    public Object1Model GetObject1(string slug, int modifier)
    {
        var obj = Array.Find(Object1Catalogue.object1List, item => item.slug == slug);
        return obj.ToModel(modifier);
    }

    ...

    private T StreamData<T>(string fileName)
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText($"{DATABASE_PATH}/{fileName}");
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Implementation: Anywhere in the application, I can now call

```
Object1Model obj = CataloguesFactory.Instance.GetObject1("first-object", 5);
obj.ToString();
// returns "first-object: Lorem 20";
```

Please let me know what you think and how I can improve this structure!

Comment: If it does work but you like to have a code review, you'd better post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, indeed, three responsibilities in one. In particular, your Factory looks like the Object Pool. Looks like the Factory is tightly coupled to a single instance of the Catalogue, which  doesn't make much sense assuming there's just one catalog. However if there is more of them, you'd need a list rather than a single reference. What bothers me most here is that you actually read the list of available objects from the file, thus, it's neither a factory not even an object pool since you are never creating new instances (with `new`), your API only finds instances in the preconfigured set.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know CodeReview existed, i will post there!

Comment: @WiktorZychla the intent is for multiple Catalogues to exist, each with different Definitions, Catalogues and Models but all being generated from the same Factory.  And yes, like you say they are all preconfigured objects where the configuration is set from the json objects.  If this isn't a factory or object pool then... what is it?  And what should it be?

Comment: This is mostly the Repository, with read-only interface. More precisely, multiple repositories under a single unit of work possibly (an aggregate of multiple repositories). Make it explicit - create an interface describing your repository, make an aggregate of your repositories. Inject the aggregate into your services. This way you'll benefit from being able to switch to another implementation (for unit testing for example).

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks!  I will look up Repository Pattern and Aggregate.  It's also in part an Abstract-Factory?  Or does the fact that it's a Repository already include that fact?

Comment: Not the aggregate but the unit of work (which is an aggregate of repos). No, it's not a factory. Repository could use a factory to create instances possibly but it doesn't look like you need one.